# ls: cannot open directory: Permission denied

Tags: permissions, 16.10

I can't open a directory with `username` even after taking ownership & giving it all permissions:

```
sudo mkdir /path/to/the/directory/
sudo chown -R username:username /path/to/the/directory/
sudo chmod -R 777 /path/to/the/directory/
```

I get:

```
$sudo ls -al /path/to/the/directory/
total 0
drwxrwxrwx 1 username username   0 nov 16 15:13 .
drwx------ 1 root     root     208 nov 16 15:13 ..
$ ls -al /path/to/the/directory/
ls: cannot access '/path/to/the/directory/': Permission denied
```

What could be going on?

Comment: it is ONLY "user" if you have a user named "user". `sudo chown -R $USER:$USER  /path/to/the/directory/` is what it should  be (`$USER` will be transformed into your username) and when you consider `sudo chmod -R 777 /path/to/the/directory/` to be an answer you should not be allowed to maintain a website ;-)

Comment: @Rinzwind Don't worry, 777 is just the result of me getting crazy debugging! :-)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You have no rights on the parent directory

```
drwx------ 1 root     root   208 nov 16 15:13 ..
```

You must have the x rights on the parent directory to pass thru this directory

```
drwx--x--x 1 root     root   208 nov 16 15:13 ..
```

to do that :

```
sudo chmod go+x /path/to/the
```

Comment: Normally, all directories can be read by default by all users (except /root) so you shouldn't have this problem. However, `drwx------ 1 root     root   208 nov 16 15:13 ..` tells you that the parent directory can't be read by your user. You have to add permissions to the user to read the folder

Comment: yes on all parents