# Folder permission problem

Tags: permissions, filesystem

I have some permission problem, for example, folder named "folder1" was created by user debian-transmission and my user eduardo dont have have permission to access this folder.

I tried change folder group owner and use ACL, but nothing work.

Could you help me understand this problem?

```
$ cd folder1
-bash: cd: folder1/: Permission denied
$ ls -lsh
8.0K drwxrwxr-x+ 2 debian-transmission users 4.0K Apr 11 00:28 folder1
$ getfacl folder1
 # file: folder1/
 # owner: debian-transmission
 # group: users
 user::rwx
 user:debian-transmission:rwx
 user:eduardo:rw-
 group::rw-
 mask::rwx
 other::r-x
 default:user::rwx
 default:user:debian-transmission:rwx
 default:user:eduardo:rw-
 default:group::rw-
 default:mask::rwx
 default:other::r-x
$ id
uid=1001(eduardo) gid=100(users) groups=100(users),27(sudo),116(debian-transmission)
$ id debian-transmission
uid=110(debian-transmission) gid=116(debian-transmission) groups=116(debian-transmission)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To enter a dir you need execute permission (rwx or r-x). From what i'm seeing the group, **users** has only rw-. Note the missing x.

 So you have to change the permission of the folder to include the x:

```
$ sudo chmod 775 /path/to/folder1
```

This would give the group  ability to enter that directory (ie rwx).

optionally instead of changing folder1's group from **users** to **eduardo** you could add eduardo to the **users** group:

```
sudo adduser eduardo users
```

And then make **users** the group owner for folder1:

```
sudo chown -R debian-transmission:users folder1
```

have a look at [these](https://askubuntu.com/questions/850227/ls-cannot-open-directory-permission-denied)

Comment: Since OP is already a member of the `debian-transmission` group, it's better to just keep the folder under `debian-transmission`'s group ownership.

Comment: The problem was the lack of execution permission in the foler.

Thank you for your help.